# Editing comments in word using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm working on an add-in that allows replying to comments in a word document. I need to find which comment is selected and then add text to it through the code, but I can't seem to find methods for finding the selected comment or adding text to it. 
Thanks to anyone who might know how to help!

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Selection.Comments property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.comments.ASPX), Its seems to return a Comments collection that represents all the comments in the specified selection. Selecting one comment would return a collection of one element i guess.

Once you have the Comment you can use the [Range.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.text%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property to modify the Text.